# What am I missing when calculating?

Tags: ios, swift

I am pretty new with programming but I am currently learning iOS. I have been trying to build a calculator but I have some problems. For instance, when I try to calculate 2 + 2, it shows me 5. Because when I press the second number (in this case 2) it makes it 3.

Can anyone help me to fix and understand the problem?

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numberOnScreen:Double = 0
    var previousNumber:Double = 0
    var performingMath = false
    var operation = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if performingMath == true
        {
            label.text = String(sender.tag)
            numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
            performingMath = false
        }
        else
        {
            label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
            numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
        }


    }


    @IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton)
    {

        if label.text != "" && sender.tag != 11 && sender.tag != 16
        {
            previousNumber = Double(label.text!)!

            if sender.tag == 12 {
                label.text = "/"
            }
            else if sender.tag == 13 {
                label.text = "*"
            }
            else if sender.tag == 14 {
                label.text = "-"
            }
            else if sender.tag == 15 {
                label.text = "+"
            }
            operation = sender.tag
            performingMath = true
        }

        else if sender.tag == 16 {
            if operation == 12 {
                label.text = String(numberOnScreen / previousNumber)
            }
            else if operation == 13 {
                label.text = String(numberOnScreen * previousNumber)
            }
            else if operation == 14 {
                label.text = String(numberOnScreen - previousNumber)
            }
            else if operation == 15 {

                label.text = String(numberOnScreen + previousNumber)
            }
        }
        else if sender.tag == 11 {
            label.text = ""
            numberOnScreen = 0
            previousNumber = 0
            operation = 0

        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: Every exclamation mark is a crash to happen. And doing arithmetic with tags is something I have never seen before.

Comment: In the numbers method it looks like you are missing a "-1" on the sender.tag when performingMath is true. The else clause does "sender..tag-1".